# Roxygen not generating .Rd files with directory tree

Tags: r, roxygen

I have main directory with R project file, project is called "knn". I have subdirectories source (contains all .R files), data (contains .csv files used in project) and man (.Rd files should go there). I also have correct DESCRIPTION and NAMESPACE (generated by Roxygen) files in main directory.

When I use `roxygen2::roxygenize()` in my main project directory, I get `Loading knn` and no files. When I use `devtools::document()` in my main directory, I get `Updating knn documentation Loading knn`. I have no documentation or .Rd files whatsoever.

I've even tried moving all my .R files to main directory - same results. How can I generate my documentation? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Suspect you need your .R files in a directory called R?

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As commented, Roxygen assumes all your .R scripts are in a directory called R.